# IS "rose by" correct instead of "rose to"?

Tags: meaning

In this HeadLine:

"The government is expected to report that consumer prices rose by 8.2 percent in the year through May, as inflation hovers near the fastest rate in decades."

I don't get the use of "by" in "rose by". To me it is clearly a "rising to", "By" gives me a sense of origin, for example:

"the price of a sode rose by one dollar to two dollars"

what is the deal with "rose by"???

Comment: Because it didn't rise *to* 8.2% but *by* 8.2%: it increased by 8.2%.

Answer (score 7):

It's a difference in meaning:

**Rise by x:**

> new price = old price + x

**Rise to x:**

> new price = x

"rising to" denotes the target and "rising by" the way to get there. The origin would be denoted with "rising from".

To combine the three:

> "The price rose *by* 1$ *from* 10$ *to* 11$"

You can compare this with other terms for movement: "I went from London to Manchester by train"

Comment: Greate Answer. A freaking nice answer